# Creating polygons that cross the dateline in R

Tags: r, gis, geospatial, polygon

How do you generate and plot polygons that cross the international dateline in R?

I believe that the following code creates a polygon that crosses the dateline. This code uses standard 180 degree longitude values (+ values for East, - values for West). Unfortunately, this does not have the expected shape when plotted.

```
# long and lat values
x <- c(-130, 120, -140, -90, -130)
y <- c(30, 30, 50, 80, 30)

# create SpatialPolygons object
p1 = Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(x, y))), "p1")
sp1 <- SpatialPolygons(list(p1))

# plot
plot(sp1, col = "red")
```

I can obtain the expected shape by converting all longitude values to degrees East, as follows:

```
# convert lat/lon to degrees East
convert_180_to_360.f <- function(longitude_value){
  ifelse(longitude_value < 0, longitude_value + 360, longitude_value)
}

x360 <- convert_180_to_360.f(x)

# create SpatialPolygons object
p2 <- Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(x360, y))), "p2")
sp2 <- SpatialPolygons(list(p2))

# plot
plot(sp2, col = "red")
```

However, this polygon can not be plotted with other spatial data that is based on +/- 180 degree latitudes.

```
library(maptools)

# get world map
data(wrld_simpl)

# plot map and polygon
plot(wrld_simpl)
plot(sp2, add = T, col = "red")
```

Is there a way to generate the polygon so that the shape is correct and it can be plotted with other standard +/-180 longitude geospatial objects?